# For a Windows Forms Application using `DataGridView`, how can I check a value in my DataSource and change the color of a separate cell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Very specific question, I know. I'm not sure how best to word this. Currently, my `cell_formatting` method will change the color of a cell based on its value:

```
    dataGridView.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.cell_formatting);


    ....


    public void cell_formatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("LocCode"))
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I actually need to do is check a different column index than that of the one I'm changing the color of. There's a column `color` that will decide  what color the `LocCode` cell will change to.

I imagine there's a way to catch which item in my `dataGridView.DataSource` is being looked at while inside `cell_formatting()`, but I don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I imagine there's a way to catch which item in my dataGridView.DataSource is being looked at while inside cell_formatting(), but I don't know how to access it.

Sure there is.

First, use the [`DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs.RowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs.RowIndex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property to get the index of the row being formatted. Then use the index to the get the corresponding `DataRow` object, and finally use the [`DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property to get the corresponding data source object, casting it to the appropriate type:

```
var item = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as YourDataSourceObjectType;
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need. I'll implement and let you know!

Comment: Alright, looks good but I inevitably get an our of range error when I implement.

[Snippet of code](http://imgur.com/a/G9XZF)

Comment: You are using `e.ColumnIndex` while you should use `e.RowIndex` :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use DataTable to get the color value. Here is an simple example for you.

I made a Table and add 3 records in it.

[image: records]

In form_load, data loaded to DataGridView,

```
DataTable dt;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=serverName;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TestTable", conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Then, here we came cell_formatting event,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("TestName")) // LocCode
            {
                if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() != "") // Check for extra line
                {
                    string a = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Color"].ToString(); //current row's Color column value.
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromName(a); // color as backcolor
                }

            }
        }
```

Output;

[image: result]

Hope helps,