# How to change DataGridView cell color based on value of Combobox?

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

I have a datagridview as below:

[image]

I would like:

- When the form load, if the `Gender` column's value is Male, the corresponding color cell of column `Name` will be White
- When if changes the value of the column `Gender`: Male → Female, color cell of the column `Name` will be DarkGray,
  otherwise if changes the value of the column `Gender`: Female → Male, color cell of the column `Name` will be White

I tried it but I am not able to do it:

```
    private void dataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.CurrentCell;

        if (dgv.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString().Trim() == "Male")
        {
            // Male
            dgv.Rows[cell.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            // Female
            dgv.Rows[cell.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        }
    }
```

OR:

```
    private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

        if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Gender"))
        {
            if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString().Trim() == "Male")
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
            }
        }

        //if (dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString().Trim() == "Male")
        //{
        //    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        //}
    }
```

Any tips on these will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [CellFormatting event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx).The example there may help you do what you want

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540935/for-a-windows-forms-application-using-datagridview-how-can-i-check-a-value-in/39541363#39541363) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do not use the `DataTable` that used `DataGridViewRow` to display data, then how? Sorry I'm newbie C#

Comment: @MinhKiyo focus on Cell Formatting event.

Comment: Berkay: I updated my question used `dataGridView_CellFormatting`, but it cannot

Comment: @MinhKiyo Debug please, I can't help you with this way.

Comment: Have you debugged your application to see what is `e.Value.ToString()` ? And BTW, you should change `e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;` and `e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;` to `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;` and `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll review my code.

Comment: Pikoh: Yes exactly , it run well. But must click other cell, the new color is updated. Is there any way that color is updated as soon as the value of the combobox change?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try to add this code to the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event handler: `dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);` I'll add an answer with all the code.

Comment: @MinhKiyo you can cast the combobox cell to a combobox and wire a selected index changed event to it using a delegate. That way you can update colors the moment the combobox value is changed.

Comment: Pikoh, Berkay, Niklas: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the Background color you must subscribe to the `CellFormatting` event. Then add this code to the event handler:

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Gender"))
    {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString().Trim() == "Male")
        {
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["name"].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        }
    }

}
```

To cause a validation when a new value is selected in your `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`,subscribe to the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event and try this code in its handler:

```
private void dataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.CurrentCell;
    if (cell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
    {
        dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        dgv.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It was exactly what I wanted to run. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you a working example, I am changing ForeColor instead of Back, but the concept is the same. You need to apply a default:

```
this.dgvUsers.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Then based on what your trigger is, you need to assign a handler:

```
dgvUsers.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dgvUsers_CellFormatting);
this.Controls.Add(dgvUsers);
```

Then to handle the event, it will look something like this:

```
// Handle user going inactive or being reactivated
private void dgvUsers_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView row = dgvUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    if (row != null && row.Row.ItemArray[7].Equals("N"))
    {
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
    else
    {
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Unlike the accepted answer, this uses styles to have to change defined in a single place.